# How do I use the Discoverer module with pygi GstPbutils?

Tags: python, introspection, gstreamer

I'm trying to port some pygtk music player code to pygi which uses gst's discoverer module.

```
from gi.repository import Gst, GstPbutils

def on_discovered(discoverer, ismedia):
    print("%s -- %s" %( discoverer.tags.get('title', 'Unknown'),
                        discoverer.tags.get('artist', 'Unknown')))

Gst.init(None)
location = "file:///srv/Music/molly_hatchet-the_creeper.mp3"
discoverer = GstPbutils.Discoverer()
discoverer.discover_uri(location)
discoverer.connect('discovered', on_discovered)
```

When I attempt to run this I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py:43: Warning: g_object_get_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py:43: Warning: g_object_ref_sink: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)

** (python:21482): CRITICAL **: pygobject_register_wrapper: assertion `PyObject_TypeCheck(self, &PyGObject_Type)' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py:43: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
```

Unfortunately documentation on this pygi module seems a bit sparse.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to make this work?

Comment: Never did actually.  Due to this and a few other issues I ended up switching from gstreamer to vlc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of generic GST discoverer invocation :

```
import sys

import gobject
gobject.threads_init()

import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst
from gst.extend.discoverer import Discoverer

def on_discovered(discoverer, ismedia, infile):
    print '\non_discovered:', infile
    discoverer.print_info()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        print 'Audio file: %s ' % sys.argv[0]
        discoverer = Discoverer(sys.argv[1])
        discoverer.connect('discovered', on_discovered, sys.argv[1])

        # The MainLoop
        mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
        gobject.idle_add(discoverer.discover)
        mainloop.run()

    else:
        print 'Usage: %s <input_file>' % sys.argv[0]
```

EDIT : If you just want the tags, use [this](https://gist.github.com/xaccrocheur/6203346#file-discover) :

Comment: Another example : http://www.openshotvideo.com/2008/06/discover-media-information-using-python.html

Answer (score 5):

I successfully used the `GstPbutils` module with the following code (note that this use version `1.2` of gstreamer)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print >> sys.stderr, "usage %s <filename>" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)

    Gst.init(None)
    GObject.threads_init()

    discoverer = GstPbutils.Discoverer()
    discoverer.connect('discovered', on_discovered)
    info = discoverer.discover_uri(sys.argv[1])

    # video info
    print '# video'
    for vinfo in info.get_video_streams():
        print vinfo.get_caps().to_string().replace(', ', '\n\t')

    # audio info
    print '# audio'
    for ainfo in info.get_audio_streams():
        print ainfo.get_caps().to_string().replace(', ', '\n\t')
```

with which I obtain an output like the following

```
$ python source.py 'file:///home/gipi/Videos/Adventure Time - Season 2/Adventure time - 1x24 - Heat Signature.mp4'
# video
video/x-h264
        stream-format=(string)avc
        alignment=(string)au
        level=(string)4.1
        profile=(string)high
        codec_data=(buffer)01640029ffe1001967640029ac5208014016ec04400000fa40002ee023c60c626001000668e88ecb22c0
        width=(int)1280
        height=(int)720
        framerate=(fraction)24000/1001
        pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
        parsed=(boolean)true
# audio
audio/mpeg
        mpegversion=(int)4
        framed=(boolean)true
        stream-format=(string)raw
        level=(string)2
        base-profile=(string)lc
        profile=(string)lc
        codec_data=(buffer)1190
        rate=(int)48000
        channels=(int)2
```

The documentation is a little tricky since the various data type are not defined explicitely (for example `GstDiscovererAudioInfo`); BTW you can find some documentation [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-gstdiscoverer.html)

Comment: This answer ROCKS :) Given that we're now deep into the Python3 era, IMHO this should be the accepted one, not mine